# controller is not loading whenever associated html is opened in IONIC V1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my app I am trying to dashboard.html and associated controller would load if the condition is true, but the problem is first time it will load the controller but from second time it is opening html page but not only loading controller.

What may the wrong where I did mistake please help me to find.

**app.js**

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
.state('app', {
  url: '/app',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
  controller: 'AutoLoginCtrl'
})
.state('app.autoLog', {
  url: '/autoLog',
  controller: 'AutoLoginCtrl'
})
.state('app.search', {
  url: '/search',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.browse', {
  url: '/browse',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
    }
  }
})
.state('app.profileInfo', {
  url: '/profileInfo/:success',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/profileInfo.html',
      controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.profile', {
  url: '/profile/:data',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/profile.html',
      controller: 'ProfileCtrl'

    }
  }
})

.state('app.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.dog', {
  url: '/dog',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/dog.html',
      controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
    }
  }
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/autoLog');
```

**loginController.js**

If the below condition is true then is will call .state('app.dashboard')

```js
if (data[0].Userprofile1 == true && data[0].Userprofile2 == true) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    console.log('My profile setup is over');
    $state.go("app.dashboard");
}
```

**dashboardController.js**

```js
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state, UserService) {
 $scope.pageName = 'Hi i am user';
 console.log('Hi home controller loading')
 var userStatus = UserService.getUser()
      console.log(userStatus);
      if (userStatus != null) {
       $scope.ersrserer = userStatus.userID;
       console.log($scope.ersrserer);
      }  else {
        console.log('its empty');
      }
})
```

first time when it calls dashboard.html it will load controller also but from second time it will not load controller, what went wrong here?

Comment: Of all of those states, which one loads the dashboardCtrl that you have written above? Your app.dashboard has -no- controller. So if that controller above is loading somewhere, I'm guessing you name it something else? Is it perhaps the AutoLoginCtrl referenced in the 'app' state?

Comment: app.dashboard states loads dashboardController.

Comment: dashboard.html contains ng-controller="dashboardCtrl" tag.

Answer (score 0):

A state requires a controller to be initialized with it, you have add the controller and inside the state you can add a resolve block:

```
 .state('your state', {
    url: '/url',
    resolve: {
        someName: function(inject here) {
            //return something, or redirect to a state...etc
        }
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/something.html',
    controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
})
```